# sigma-fields on Z?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am given a practice exercise to find all the $\sigma$-fields ($\mathcal{A}$ on the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\{kn+b:n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $k=1,2,..$ and $b=0,1,...,k-1$.

On the top of my head, I can tell that the power set of $\mathbb{Z}$ ($2^{\mathbb{Z}}$) would be such a sigma-field, but is there any other $\sigma$ field that satisfies condition?

:S thank you,

Comment: Try to find out which $\sigma$-field the given sets generate. Every $\sigma$-field that contains this will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be such a $\sigma$-field.

We first show that, for any integer $x$, the singleton $\{x\}$ is in $A$.

In fact, for any $k \geq 1$, the set $S_k = \{kn + x: n \in \Bbb Z\}$ is in $A$. Therefore, the intersection of all $S_k$, which is equal to the singleton $\{x\}$, is in $A$.

Now any subset of $\Bbb Z$ is a countable union of singletons, hence must be in $A$.

It follows that $A$ is equal to the power set of $\Bbb Z$.